# VBA: Finding a sheet by name across workbooks and copy a sheet next to it

Tags: vba, excel

I am kind of lost with the workbook reference and nesting if condition. What I want to achieve is,

1. Find a workbook which has a sheet name say "EMPLOYEE".
2. Check is there any sheet name say "COMPANY" in the above workbook, Delete if exist.
3. Copy sheet "COMPANY" from the Active workbook (not active sheet) to the above workbook.

I am reaching so far but not sure how to copy the non-active-sheet "COMPANY" from the active workbook to the workbook which we find in point 1.

Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

```
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
       For Each ws In wb.Sheets
       If ws.Name = "EMPLOYEE" Then wb.Sheets("COMPANY").Delete
       Next ws
    Next wb
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: assign activeworkbook a var before you start then ref as normal,   you need to also check if COMPANY exists before you try delete it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By *Active workbook* do you mean the one with the code module running the operation? If that is the case, then `ThisWorkbook` can be used to reference it as the parent of the *Company* worksheet you wish to copy to the workbook you just deleted a *Company* worksheet from.

```
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   On Error Resume Next
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        For Each ws In wb.Sheets
            If ws.Name = "EMPLOYEE" Then
                wb.Sheets("COMPANY").Delete
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Company").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
            End If
        Next ws
    Next wb
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

I find `ThisWorkbook` to be more definitive than `ActiveWorkbook` particularly in operations like this where the focus may (by default) be changed to the workbook receiving the copy of the *Company* worksheet.

Alternately, you can assign a worksheet object reference to the *Company* worksheet you wish to copy across and use that reference repeatedly as you progress through the workbooks collection.